# Rename a mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, rename, procedure

Does anyone know what is the syntax for renaming a mysql stored procedure/function? Or is this even supported in MySQL? I've been googling this for several minutes...

Comment: This is documented http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,274538,274563#msg-274563 here as a workaround. A stored procedure to rename could be found here http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/rename-mysql-stored-procedures/819 . A feature request  with submission in 2007 is apparently still open if this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27793 is still valid.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try this

```
 UPDATE `mysql`.`proc`
SET name = '<new_proc_name>',
specific_name = '<new_proc_name>'
WHERE db = '<database>' AND
  name = '<old_proc_name>';
```

Also note: If have granted privileges to users for this procedure you will need to update the procedure name in procs_priv as well.

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`procs_priv`
SET Routine_name = '<new_proc_name>'
WHERE Db = '<database>' AND
  Routine_name = '<old_proc_name>';
 FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Source: [MySQL Forums :: Newbie :: Rename Stored Procedure Syntax](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,274538,274563)

Comment: Do you need any specific privileges to change that table?'

Comment: Is there a variant of this statement where you don't need to specify the database name, just use the active database?

Comment: @Gruber, yes – simply use the function `DATABASE()` to get the current database name, at append it as a condition: `UPDATE mysql.proc SET name = ..., specific_name = ... WHERE name = ... AND db = DATABASE()`

Comment: Also don't forgot to change caller events of the stored procedure:           
alter event event_RunSP1 on schedule every 60 second DO call <new_proc_name>;