# ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist while calling a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using this thread -

[Rename a mysql procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644684/rename-a-mysql-procedure)

to rename a stored procedure

Here upon trying the command as shown in the answer -

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc`
SET name = '<new_proc_name>',
specific_name = '<new_proc_name>'
WHERE db = '<database>' AND
  name = '<old_proc_name>';
```

I get the error -

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist while calling a stored procedure
```

Here regarding the other questions regarding `mysql.proc` does not exit, none address the specific problem of calling a stored procedure.

Comment: That table was removed in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: I [can't find even a feature request](https://bugs.mysql.com/search.php?search_for=rename+procedure&status%5B%5D=Open&severity=-4&limit=10&order_by=&cmd=display&phpver=&os=0&os_details=&bug_age=0&cpu_arch=0&cpu_arch_details=&last_updated=0&tags=&similar=) for this.

Answer (score 5):

The `mysql.proc` table was removed in MySQL 8.0. See [No more mysql.proc in MySQL 8.0](https://ocelot.ca/blog/blog/2017/08/22/no-more-mysql-proc-in-mysql-8-0/)

You can use `information_schema.routines` to get information about stored procedures. But this is a read-only view, you can't update it. So I don't think there's any simple way to rename procedures any more. You may be able to use dynamic SQL to define the procedure with the new name using this information.

EDIT:

Unfortunately, the above is not possible just in MySQL, because `CREATE PROCEDURE` can't be executed using `PREPARE`, and `information_schema.routines` doesn't contain all the information needed to recreate the procedure. You could do it in an external language by performing a `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` query and then replacing the name to form a new query.

Comment: Please show me how to use dynamic SQL to define the procedure with new name

Comment: I [got this far](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f56fb2e96b920c6d277285e1deaf0e4) before giving up.

Comment: You're pretty close, but you're missing the parameter list in the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Of course, which isn't in the IS view. And take all the other definer/sql mode args to recreate it exactly. [apparently](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d411c56783cd331f724562c5640b0ccd) "This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet".
So grabbing the sql from mysqldump --routines, editing the SQL for the routine name and re-importing is maybe less burdensome. I agree with you @PayelSenapati this is pretty horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend avoid fiddling with *any* mysql table directly.

Use `show create procedure old_proc_name`

And then `create procedure new_proc_name ....`

And drop the old `drop procedure old_proc_name`

Comment: It has the main problem of writing the entire procedure again, for example if the procedure is thousand line one, it will be hugely frustrating to write it again to just change the name